# How to initialize structure having unint_t as flexible array member?

Tags: c, arduino, flexible-array-member

I define a struct, have a one-member the type is uint8_t, this member store mac address.

Programming on Arduino IDE.

Struct:

```
typedef struct devInfo{
  uint8_t address[];
  unsigned int count;
  unsigned int filePos;
}struct_devInfo;
```

- Quesion 1:

I use these two ways to give a value but cannot assign value to variable.

> Method 1 >
> struct_devInfo slave = {{0xA1, 0xB2, 0xC3, 0xD4, 0xE5, 0xF6}, 0, 0};

> Method 2 >
> slave.address[] = {0xA1, 0xB2, 0xC3, 0xD4, 0xE5, 0xF6};

How can I access this type of value?

- Question 2:

I will use the variables of this structure,
salve1, slave2... etc.

In addition to the structure, is there some better way?
Can you demonstrate?

Comment: "Doesn't work" how? I would have expected method 1 to work, but not method 2 since you can't assign arrays. For question 2, you want "some better way" but it's not clear to what you're referring.

Comment: @PaulHankin My mean is I want to store a value to uint8_t this variable, I try to use two ways to do this thing.

Comment: What Paul is saying is that you should [edit] your question and tell HOW you know it does not work. An error message for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A struct with a flexible array member needs to be the last member in the struct. Change to

```
typedef struct devInfo{
  unsigned int count;
  unsigned int filePos;
  uint8_t address[];
}struct_devInfo;
```

Then you need to allocate enough memory:

```
struct_devInfo *p = malloc(sizeof *p + size);
```

Then you could do this:

```
const uint8_t initArr[] = {0xA1, 0xB2, 0xC3, 0xD4, 0xE5, 0xF6};
memcpy(p, initArr, sizeof initArr);
```

But since it seems to be a field that does not require a flexible member, I'd use this instead:

```
typedef struct devInfo{
  unsigned int count;
  unsigned int filePos;
  uint8_t address[6]; // Specify the size
}struct_devInfo;
```

Then you don't need to allocate memory

Comment: Another solution could be to make it `address[6]` (or whatever the maximum size is of the device address). Then it would still be key to use `memcpy` to assign the value. The `malloc` would not be required.

Comment: If I want to give a value when declaring variables, like this strcut_devInfo slave = {MACADDRESS, 0 ,5};, can i do this?

Comment: @Rain With a flexible member, no